Set image size when adding from URL in Google Sheets App Script
i have a script that works. It inserts images into spread sheet cells based on the URL in another cell.
What i can't find is how to set the standard width of the images so they will all come in at a legible size for me to view them. The images are different dimensions / shapes so i figure only setting the width is an easy fix.
Any help would be great.
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu(' Automation')
    .addItem('Insert Images', 'insertCellImages')
    .addToUi();
}

function insertCellImages() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  // Loop through all rows
  for (let row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++) {
    let url = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue(); // Column E
    if (url && typeof url === 'string' && url.trim() !== "") {
      let imageRange = sheet.getRange(row, 9); // Column N
      
      try {
        let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
        imageRange.setValue(image);
        Logger.log("Inserted image in row " + row);
      } catch (error) {
        Logger.log("Error in row " + row + ": " + error.toString());
        imageRange.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Image insertion complete!');
}

I searched but couldn't find anything that works for Message Bird URLs (not drive specific URLs)

Although I do not know your image size, in your situation, how about changing the row height and the column width instead of the image size? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

This question is similar to: How can I adjust row width & column width of google sheet dynamically using apps script?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PatrickdC I think it's a separate question. Just because the answer is the same doesn't make it the same.

You're setting the value of the cell to an image. So the size of the image is constrained by the width of the column and the height of the row.
You can either auto size rows and columns or set them to a specific value.
See this answer for details on changing the size of rows/columns with app script
